# How can I start a socket REPL in Clojure 1.8 from leiningen or boot?

Tags: clojure

In the following link
http://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main#_launching_a_socket_server

it has detailed info about how to start socket REPL form java, but since I am using lein, so how to start from lein. If start from boot is good to run, I could also try to use boot.

Comment: Leiningen automatically starts the repl on a socket. Look at the banner it prints at startup to see which one it picked.

Comment: @dsm the author is talking about the new socket REPL in Clojure 1.8, not Leiningen's REPL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To start a socket repl, you need to pass this option to the JVM

```
-Dclojure.server.repl="{:port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}"
```

In Leiningen, add this to your `project.clj`.

```
:jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.server.repl={:port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}"] ; notice that the map is not quoted.
```

and in Boot, export the environment variable `BOOT_JVM_OPTIONS`

```
export BOOT_JVM_OPTIONS='-Dclojure.server.repl="{:port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}"'
```

Once your REPL is running, you can run `telnet` from a different terminal to connect to the socket REPL. REPLception!

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
user=> (+ 1 1)
2
user=>
```

Comment: it's clear for boot as "export" is a linux command and I know how to use it. but for lein, you use ":jvm-opts...", should we I put? put it into project.clj?

Answer (score 2):

boot has an upcoming [`socket-server` task](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/blob/f66aaf387740dc5968bde3f74a8761da154cab13/boot/core/src/boot/task/built_in.clj#L483). As of boot 2.7.1, a version that includes this task hasn't been released yet.

In the meantime you can use the following commands to launch Socket REPLs. To launch a Clojure process with a Socket REPL listening on port 50505 using boot, use:

```
boot -i "(do (require 'clojure.core.server) (clojure.core.server/start-server {:port 50505 :name :repl :accept 'clojure.core.server/repl}))" wait
```

Using Leiningen:

```
JVM_OPTS='-Dclojure.server.myrepl={:port,50505,:accept,clojure.core.server/repl}' lein repl
```

Using a pain Clojure jar:

```
java -Dclojure.server.myrepl="{:port 50505 :accept clojure.core.server/repl}" -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar
```